# Angular.js: Update (data-bind) only one item of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend.aktuell">
            <input type="text" ng-model="friend.aktuell[key]"> 
        </span>
      <quick-datepicker ng-model="auditDate"></quick-datepicker>
      <button ng-click="audit(auditDate, friend._id)" class="btn btn-info">Audit</button>
  </li>
```

Now how can I update only the input fields of the `friend[index]` - so to speak - that has been clicked via the audit button?

e.g.

```
   $scope.audit = function(auditDate, id){
            $scope.friends[1].aktuell = {someData:someValues}; // this works if the index is hard coded
        });
    };
```

Above works if the index '1' is hard coded into 'friends[1]', but of course I want to no update this in the second input row, but in the one that has been clicked.

Idea: Can I pass the current clicked "indexifier" to my audit function or alternatively can I alter the input fields where "friend._id = friend._id"?

Screenshot:

[image: screen-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is $index variable available inside ng-repeat:

```
ng-click="audit(auditDate, $index)"
```

Comment: Great answer, as bonus question, would you happen to know how I alter the CSS of the ng-model:auditDate (the "Click to Set Date" Button) of a particular index?

Comment: `style="background-color: #{{generateColor($index)}}"` for example, or `class="button-{{$index}}"` or `ng-class="{'custom-button': $index % 2 == 0}"` if you want to stylize only even buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the `friend` reference instead of passing its index?

```
<button ng-click="audit(auditDate, friend)" class="btn btn-info">Audit</button>
```

And on the controller:

```
$scope.audit = function(auditDate, friend){
        friend.aktuell = {someData:someValues};
    });
};
```